# Программа падает, если переопределить конструктор копирования

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Demo{
private:
    int size = 0;
    int *m = nullptr;
public:
    Demo() = default;
    Demo(int n) :size(n){
        m = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            m[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    Demo(const Demo &c){
        m = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            m[i] = c.m[i];
    }

    ~Demo(){
        delete[] m;
    }

    void show(){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            cout << m[i] << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    Demo m(15),n;   

    m.show();
    n = m;
    n.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Программа работает, вроде копирует но при запуске. В чём проблема? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем примере, если уж на то пошло, вообще не используется конструктор копирования. Определять его, разумеется, надо, но к этому падению он никакого отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как Вам уже ответил @zenden2k - Вы не переопределили оператор присваивания, который используется в строчке `n = m;`.
Я предлагаю несколько иной способ реализации `operator=` - через `swap`. Это даёт строгую гарантию касательно исключений и вообще является предпочтительной практикой:

```
Demo(const Demo &c)
{
    m = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        m[i] = c.m[i];
}

Demo& operator=(const Demo &c)
{
    Demo tmp(c);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}

void swap(Demo& other)
{
    std::swap(size, other.size);
    std::swap(m, other.m);
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется создание потенциально ненужного объекта чересчур затратным...

Comment: @Qwertiy, так никаких лишних затрат по сравнение с реализацией "в лоб" нет

Comment: Я имел в виду случай `Demo & operator = (Demo &&c)` - если он проходит через текущую реализацию `Demo & operator = (const Demo &c)` и `swap`, то происходит лишнее выделение памяти и копирование массива.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я просто не добавлял оператор перемещения. Не подумал.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно перегрузить также **оператор присваивания**, а не только конструктор копирования.

```
Demo& operator=(const Demo &c){
    if ( this != &c) {
        delete[] m;
        size = c.size;
        m = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        m[i] = c.m[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, а тогда зачем нужен конструктор копирования? И в каких случаях он нужен ?

Comment: @zenden2k, c memory leak? Это Вы решили на самостоятельное обучение оставить парню оставить? :)

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov чтобы можно было написать `Demo m  = n;` и не только.

Comment: @margosh я не сильно вчитывался в код

Comment: @zenden2k,  зачем вчитываться, вы же оператор присваивания предложили, его код стандартный, проверки на самоприсваивание нет

Comment: @margosh ну простите меня грешного :)

Comment: Такой вопрос, после того как я напишу оператор присваивания оператор копирования не нужен? Без него всё работает

Comment: @IlyaTikhonov, конкретно в Вашем коде *конструктор копирования* не используется, но он, безусловно, нужен. [Правило трёх](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_трёх_(C%2B%2B_программирование))

Answer (score 0):

Хотя к ошибке это не относится, было бы неплохо ещё добавить конструктор перемещения:

```
Demo(Demo &&c){
    swap(size, c.size);
    swap(m, c.m);
}
```

А ошибка, похоже, действительно в отсутствии операторов присваивания. Их можно скопировать с конструкторов копирования и перемещения, не забыв вернуть `*this` по ссылке.